# how can I find a non-printing character that is messing up another tool with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've grabbed some code from a blog post and I'd like to convert it to coffeescript. However, there's an illegal character in the code somewhere, so js2coffee fails. All the suggestions that I've found just talk about whitespace. Showing the whitespace characters hasn't helped.

```
angular
.module('lvl.services',[])
.factory('uuid', function() {
    var svc = {
        new: function() {
            function _p8(s) {
                var p = (Math.random().toString(16)+"000000000").substr(2,8);
                return s ? "-" + p.substr(0,4) + "-" + p.substr(4,4) : p ;
            }
            return _p8() + _p8(true) + _p8(true) + _p8();
        },

        empty: function() {
          return '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';
        }
    };

    return svc;
});
```

How can I find this illegal character using Sublime Text 2? I copied the text to Windows Notepad++ (I'm in a VM) and then back to Sublime Text 2 (in Ubuntu) and the illegal character went away -- it converted fine using `js2coffee`. `js2coffee` doesn't tell me what the illegal character is or what line number it is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/linux-display-show-file-contents-tabs-line-breaks-non-printing-characters/?

The last example, using "cat -A /path/to/myfile" seems to display all characters regardless of visibility. Maybe try that under your Ubuntu VM?

I can also think of doing that and saving the output to a file, and then do the same but with the file you already cleaned via N++ -> ST2, and do a diff, just out of curiosity to see which char was the culprit.

Comment: I'd try that but the file is gone. I must've fixed it by copying to another app. `cat -A` seems to be a good bash level solution. It seems odd (as in deficient) that ST2 can't accomplish this.

Comment: Yes, it's very strange that ST2 doesn't have something that, I would adventure to say, a lot of people must use/need.